# T-SQL variable vs. inline conversion performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, azure-sql-database, query-optimization

Imagine a T-SQL query that needs to determine if something is on a date. There are two versions.

```
declare @theDate as date = convert(date,'1900-01-01');

select * 
from someTable 
where someTable.Date = @theDate;
```

and

```
select * 
from someTable 
where someTable.Date = convert(date,'1900-01-01');
```

In the second example, is it running the conversion once per row? Is there any performance benefit to always putting these in variables?

Comment: It would be resolved once.

Comment: the second example would allow the query optimiser to see the literal value of the query - which potentially could allow more accurate cardinality estimates - if the column statistics are up-to-date. This could lead to a different execution plan between the two methods if you have a non covering index on `Date`

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at the "Execution plan" of the two queries.
In both cases, the cost is exactly the same.

[image: Execution plans]

Comment: your screenshot doesn't demonstrate anything about the cost between the two queries.

Comment: On a noon-indexed table it needs to scan the whole thing anyway, so of course it's going to be the same. Now try it on an indexed table

Comment: Please do not draw conclusions from a single example like this - it VERY MUCH matters between these two patterns in other scenarios.